# ReactJS instant Search with input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making my first react project. Im new in JS, HTML, CSS and even web app programming.

What i want to do it is a Search input label. Now its look like this:

[image]

Like you can see i have some list of objects and text input.

I Have two components, my **`ProjectList.js`** with **`Search.js`** component...

```
class ProjectsList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search projects={this.props.projects} />
        <ListGroup>
          {this.props.projects.map(project => {
            return <Project project={project} key={project.id} />;
          })}
        </ListGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectsList;
```

... and `ProjectList.js` displays `Project.js`:

How looks **`Search.js`** (its not ended component)

```
class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: ""
  };

  handleInputChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          ref={input => (this.search = input)}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <p />
       </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

My `project` have `name` property. Could you tell me how to code `Search.js` component poperly, to change displaying `projects` dynamically based on input in text label? for example, `return Project` only, if text from input match (i want to search it dynamically, when i start typing `m`... it shows all projects started on `m` etc).

How to make that Search input properly? How to make it to be universal, for example to Search in another list of objects? And how to get input from Search back to Parent component?

For now, in react dev tools whatever i type there i get `length: 0`

Thanks for any advices!

**EDIT:**

If needed, my `Project.js` component:

```
class Project extends Component {
  state = {
    showDetails: false
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       showDetails: false
    };
  }

  toggleShowProjects = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showDetails: !prevState.showDetails
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonToolbar>
        <ListGroupItem className="spread">
          {this.props.project.name}
        </ListGroupItem>
        <Button onClick={this.toggleShowProjects} bsStyle="primary">
          Details
        </Button>
        {this.state.showDetails && (
          <ProjectDetails project={this.props.project} />
        )}
      </ButtonToolbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Project;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a "generic" search box, perhaps you could do something like the following:

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    const { projects, filterProject, onUpdateProjects } = this.props;
    onUpdateProjects(projects);
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {

    const query = event.currentTarget.value;
    const { projects, filterProject, onUpdateProjects } = this.props;

    const filteredProjects = projects.filter(project => !query || filterProject(query, project));

    onUpdateProjects(filteredProjects);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
       </form>
    );
  }
}
```

This revised version of `Search` takes some additional `props` which allows it to be reused as required. In addition to the `projects` prop, you also pass `filterProject` and `onUpdateProjects` callbacks which are provided by calling code. The `filterProject` callback allows you to provide custom filtering logic for each `<Search/>` component rendered. The `onUpdateProjects` callback basically returns the "filtered list" of projects, suitable for rendering in the parent component (ie `<ProjectList/>`).

The only other significant change here is the addition of `visibleProjects` to the state of `<ProjectList/>` which tracks the visible (ie filtered) projects from the original list of `projects` passed to `<ProjectList/>`:

```js
class Project extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{ this.props.project }</div>
    );
  }
}

class ProjectsList extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    
    this.setState({ visibleProjects : [] })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Search projects={this.props.projects} filterProject={ (query,project) => (project == query) } onUpdateProjects={ projects => this.setState({ visibleProjects : projects }) }  />
        <div>
          {this.state.visibleProjects.map(project => {
            return <Project project={project} key={project.id} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Search extends React.Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    
    const { projects, filterProject, onUpdateProjects } = this.props;
    onUpdateProjects(projects);
  }
  
  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    
    const query = event.currentTarget.value;
    const { projects, filterProject, onUpdateProjects } = this.props;
    
    const filteredProjects = projects.filter(project => !query || filterProject(query, project));
    
    onUpdateProjects(filteredProjects);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
       </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ProjectsList projects={[0,1,2,3]} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Pretty impresive! Thanks for your time. Im new in React, could you tell me, did i can hard copy-paste it to my project and looks, if its work? The script needed to be in `index.html`? Of course, `Project` need to be as mine not as yours in answer ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) You should be able to copy components `ProjectsList` and `Search` directly. I think the only thing you will need to change is  `extends React.Component` to `extends Component`

Comment: I will try it in hours, Thanks a lot, if i will have any issues, i will coment. Or if it will work, of course i will mark it as answer. That JS scripts i need to add in `index.html` ? What it do?

Comment: Ok great - if you have any projects just comment here and I'll try and help you. If you need to put this code directly in `index.html` then you should be able to copy and paste it into a `<script>/* code goes here*/</script>` block directly in your HTML. Make sure the libraries from cloudflare (as shown above in snippet) are included in your HTML first.

Comment: @michasaucer just remembered, please also note that I replaced `<ListGroup>` with `<div>` above so that the snippet would work . Please make sure you update that also when you try the code in your project :)

Answer (score 2):

I will assumes both your Search and ProjectList component have a common parent that contains the list of your projects.
If so, you should pass a function into your Search component props, your Search component will then call this function when the user typed something in the search bar.  This will help your parent element decide what your ProjectsLists needs to render :

```
handleInputChange = () => {
    this.props.userSearchInput(this.search.value);
    this.setState({
        query: this.search.value
    });
};
```

And now, here is what the parent element needs to include :

```
searchChanged = searchString => {
    const filteredProjects = this.state.projects.filter(project => project.name.includes(searchString))
    this.setState({ filteredProjects })
}
```

With this function, you will filter out the projects that includes the string the user typed in their names, you will then only need to put this array in your state and pass it to your ProjectsList component props

You can find the documentation of the String [includes function here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

You can now add this function to the props of your Search component when creating it :

```
<Search userSearchInput={searchChanged}/>
```

And pass the filtered array into your ProjectsList props :

```
<ProjectsList projects={this.state.filteredProjects}/>
```

---

Side note : Try to avoid using refs, the onCHnage function will send an "event" object to your function, containing everything about what the user typed :

```
handleInputChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target
    this.props.userSearchInput(value);
    this.setState({
        query: value
    });
};
```

You can now remove the ref from your code

Comment: I Invoke components in this way so i think, ProjectLists is parent to Project, Project is child. `App.js` => `ProjectsList.js` => `Project.js`. Thanks for your answer, i will check it soon!